# Angular: strictTemplates - How to set boolean and numbers in Templates properly?

Tags: angular, angular-ivy

I set `strictTemplates:true` and use in a HTML template the following

```
<textarea matInput matAutosizeMaxRows="4" matTextareaAutosize="true"
```

I receive from the compiler

```
 error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
 error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

But how to set it properly in the HTML-Templates (to avoid the error)?

Comment: You could use the square-bracket attribute-binding notation (`[attribute]="value"`). (See the [Angular docs on binding syntax](https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax) for more info)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Wrap the property name in brackets. If you leave the brackets, the values will be interpreted as strings. With brackets, the values are interpreted as TypeScript, and are therefore typed properly.

```
<textarea matInput [matAutosizeMaxRows]="4" [matTextareaAutosize]="true"
```

Comment: thx for the reply. Is there a general guide how to treat HTML variable now 'newly'? I'm facing similar problems with $events or enums

Comment: All values expect strings should use the bracket notation. For events you need to take care that the parameters of the event handling function are typed properly. But without code it's hard to tell what is the issue. Maybe add a new question?

Comment: Perhaps you have an idea as well for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64445660/angular-stricttemplates-how-to-assign-variables-properly