# Angular: strictTemplates - How to assign variables properly

Tags: angular, angular-ivy

I have in my `Sample.html` somewhere defined

```
<input  (keydown.Enter)="onKeyEnter($event)" ...
```

In my `Sample.ts` I have defined

```
  onKeyEnter(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    ....
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
```

I get with `strictTemplates` the failure

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'KeyboardEvent'.
```

Which is somehow strange because in the `input` one can get only the a `KeyboardEvent`. Is there a way to get rid of this error? Which I see as false positive.

Comment: Looks like there is some wrong typing inside Angular. I couldn't find any more information on this. Maybe it makes sense to open a GitHub issue?

Comment: You also have a typo in your input `(keydown.enter)` (enter should be lowercase)

Comment: But the Event is caught despite the lower capital (capitol?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not the same event `keydown`than `keydown.enter`, as the own Angular say

> Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'KeyboardEvent': altKey, char, charCode, code, and 16 more.

You can use "any"

```
onKeyEnter(event: any): void {
}
```

**Update** or Event

```
onKeyEnter(event: Event): void {
}
```

Comment: But if you wanna have the `strict` options on than `any` wouldn't be allowed. BTW: you have link to your quote?

Comment: Just create a stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-drsyrq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts. NOTE, You can use also `Event` as type of the variable. (I updated the answer). I'm trying look the github fonts about keydown in Angular. If I'll find, I'll update the answer again.